# Breadcrumb not displaying correctly when i land to same page through two different pages

Tags: breadcrumbs, mvcsitemapprovider

I have two ways of getting to PageX.

Home-->PageA -->PageB -->PageX--->PageY
(One is gong to Home page and then to PageA then PageB and then to PageX)

Home-->PageX-->PageY
(Second way is directly clicking on PageX from Home)

This is my MVC.siteMap

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Page A" controller="PageAController" action="PageA" >
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="PageB" controller="PageBController" action="PageB">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="" controller="PageXController" action="PageX">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="" controller="PageYController" action="PageY" />          
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>     
</mvcSiteMapNode>

<mvcSiteMapNode title="" controller="PageXController" action="PageX">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="" controller="PageYController" action="PageY" />     
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

Now issue i am facing is when i go to PageX from Home directly. I expect breadcrumb to display 'Home/PageX' but instead i am getting 'Home / PageA / PageB / PageX'.
Where i expect 'Home/PageX/PageY' also i am getting 'Home / PageA / PageB / PageX / PageY'.

Any suggestions/help in this regard is highly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mvcsitemapprovider Multiple paths to the single page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953616/mvcsitemapprovider-multiple-paths-to-the-single-page)

Comment: Also see: [Multiple Navigation Paths to a Single Page](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Multiple-Navigation-Paths-to-a-Single-Page)